# Azure VM DNS Label

Tags: azure, dns, virtual-machine

In Azure VM I have azure dns lable. I want to configure azure dns label with ipage dns name. How to do so. I have IPage account with DNS and azure portal with public ip/ dns label. 
I want to replace dns lable with ipage domain name. 
How to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to replace dns lable with ipage domain name.

We **can't** replace dns lable with an outside domain name.

If you want to use the ipage domain name to login your Azure VM, we can add new **A record** to the ipage domain with Azure VM public IP address.

Comment: I had configure DNS Label Because By default Azure cloud allocates Dynamic address and we have dns label as well as Azure VM Public ip.

Comment: Do you mean your VM deploy in ASM mode(classic)?

Comment: If you deploy your VM in ASM module, we can create an Instance level public IP for it. If your VM deploy in ARM module, we can create a public IP to it. then point the public IP address to your ipage domain.

Comment: Thanks for you concern